# Difference between .mysql and .sql for MySQL backups extensions

Tags: mysql

When I do a mysqldump in commmand line, I use the `.sql` extension to save the file, however, I've installed an auto-backup module on my website and the files are being saved as `.mysql` automatically. Is this unusual and do I use them the same way, by sourcing them into the database? I.E. Are the suffixes interchangeable?

Edit: Can I `source` a `.mysql` file the same way I can source a `.sql` file?

Background info: I've installed the Backup and Migrate module on Drupal and the backups are creating .mysql files, which I've never seen before.

Please note that I am not asking the difference between MySQL and SQL.

Comment: Filename suffixes are just a convention, they don't have any meaning by themselves.

Comment: Yeah. Extensions might be linked to applications in a GUI environment, so you can click on the file to load it into a default application, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix you use is unimportant whether it's `.sql`, `.mysql`, `.txt` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is by default, `mysqldump` writes information as SQL statements to the standard output.

You can get more details by [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html).